# Changing content in cufontext tag within a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, cufon

I have installed a WordPress theme which features headings like 'our sponsors' or 'featured posts'. When I inspect the element using google chrome, it shows that it is within a tag called 'cufontext' which I have never come across before (i think it is to do with javascript).

Is it possible to change the content within the cufontext tag so that it says something different like 'about me' instead of 'our sponsors'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cufon is a font-replacement technique that uses javascript to write fonts from a font file  to your browser.

So those `<cufon>` tags are generated when page renders and are not in the template files.

Simply find where 'our sponsors' text is located and replace it to your likings.

The most possible location for that text is:

- in post / page as a title
- in the template as static text

Comment: I have tried that. I have gone into every file possible and searched for 'sponsors' and its just not anywhere as text.

Comment: Can you provide URL or which theme you are using?